# Python pass by reference not working

Tags: python

Iam trying to perform pass by reference in python but it is not working

```
def fun(x,y,z):
    x=5
    y=5
    z=6
x=1
y=2
z=3

fun(x,y,z)
print(x,y,z)
```

The output that I get is

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

The output that I expected was

```
(5, 5, 6)
```

Comment: Simple data types (such as ints and floats) are _not_ passed by reference in Python. They are passed by value.

Comment: @DYZ How can I pass by reference for such data types

Comment: All passing is by value in Python, but the value is a reference to an object.  Search this site for questions about Python passing by value and reference (or "pass by object") for much more information.

Comment: Do this: `global x, y, z`

Comment: @RickyHan s solution does work however it can sometimes be considered bad practice having global variables since they can cause unforeseen side effects if there is a nameclash

Comment: You can not change immutable object inside function. That's it.

Comment: @mattjegan OP don't do this: https://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: @Rahul So is there no other solution other than using a list for passing parameters